# Can I bring duty alcohol purchased in London Heathrow airport to Chennai (destination) via Colombo airport (layover) security screening?

Tags: london, connecting-flights, alcohol, duty-free, sri-lanka

I’m confused because I’m not sure if they let liquids pass through screening in Colombo airport if it’s from a duty-free shop. Please let me know what’s the best option for me as I have only a 1-hour layover in Colombo, and hoping to bring it from Heathrow. Thanks.

Comment: Have you compared the prices with buying before you go to the airport? Taxfree shops at the airports are often not a good deal.

Comment: @Willeke I agree, I've seen on multiple occasions that prices in the duty-free stores are actually higher than buying the item outside of the airport.  So that buying before you get to the airport and packing in your checked luggage maybe the better option.

Comment: In many duty free shops they will ask you if you have a connection, and in that case wrap the bottle in a special sealed bag with the receipt visible. This is then accepted at many connection checkpoints (provided it’s an actual connection and not a self transfer), though I’m not sure this is valid everywhere.

Comment: I've never been to Colombo, but generally in Asian airports liquids in sealed duty-free bags are not accepted for transfers. It would be much safer to buy in London, and pack in check-in luggage, as recommended.

Comment: Thanks everyone! The prices are pretty similar outside and in duty free. Is it okay to bring in alcohol through check in to Chennai? I have not tried this before. Do I need to have the receipts ?